# Excel - Subtract a time just over a minute from a time just under a minute

Tags: excel, time

In excel, I have a list of lap times, around a track where the length is inconveniently around a minute mark.

That means the best lap times come in a format of, for example, 59.984 seconds (formatted as "00.000"). Thererafter, time data may be over a minute for some people, at 1:00.562 (formatted as "m:ss.000").

I need to calculate the gap, in seconds and tenths, hundredths and thousandths of a second, between eahc person's time and that of the best time.

How can I achieve this? I have tried using "0.000" and "s.000" but it doesn't work whilst some data is input as a decimal number.

Do I need to input all data sub-one minute as 0:59.984 for example? This would be a bit inconvenient, as the data is not provided in this format (and for thousands of rows, it would be onerous to manually change it).

Edit - example dataset:

```
Col A          Col B          Col C (desired output)
59.997         =A2-$A$2       0.000
59.998         =A3-$A$2       0.001
59.999         =A4-$A$2       0.002
1:00.000       =A5-$A$2       0.003
1:00.001       =A6-$A$2       0.004
1:00.002       =A7-$A$2       0.005
```

Where

A2 to A4 are formatted as 'General' and A5 to A7 are formatted as 'm:ss.000'.

The desired output would be formatted to three decimal places, with no leading zeroes. Col A should also feature no leading zeroes in the final output.

Comment: If you show us your current code, maybe we can spot something that needs adjusting.

Comment: I've edited it for a sample dataset around the problem area. :)

Comment: You might like to read this link about using milliseconds in your data:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/excel-modifies-time-with-milliseconds-when-i-try/7f976963-4c00-417d-841d-836fc40a4eba?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have come up with a solution:

```
=IF(A2>1,A2/86400,A2)-IF($A$2>1,$A$2/86400,$A$2)
```

The formula checks if the value is above 1 (as in Excel time format, the 'correctly formatted' numbers above 1 minute are being recognised as less than 1 day). If the value is above 1, then it is assumed to be my 'decimal number' which is in seconds, and not input in minutes, and so this is divided by 86,400 (seconds in a day) to get a number equivalent to the values above one minute.

Then, the two numbers can be subtracted and the result formatted. This solution works for me, but would not work for anyone trying to work with time values greater than a day, for example, as my logic compares against '1' to get the values below a minute.